# Custom a unique marker for geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

How do i custom one marker that locates my geolocation without affecting the other markers? I've been trying google developers geolocation to do but it appears that my map wouldn't appear after i added it. Does this also require the use of API as well?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.723, 103.1240),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = initMap(map);

    function initMap(map) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    }//initMap
    </script>
```

Comment: Where do you create the one marker that locates your "geolocation"?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: You're not adding geolocation in your example code :/ The examples show how to do this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation. You then need to add a marker with whatever styling you want using the `pos` value that comes back from geolocation. The documentation here shows you how to customise a marker https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers